# Matching a format string defining colour codes

Tags: regex, bash

I want to match a format string (e.g. `\033[1;42;35m`) in a bash function, so the function can accept different colour setting when printing text.

Example for format is `\033[1;42;35m`, in general `\033[NA;NB;NCm`
and want to match the `[NA;NB;NCm` part.

Am playing with

```
if [[ "$1" =~ \[[0123456789]+;[0123456789]+;[0123456789]+m ]] ; then
```

The problem is the following errors

```
./mosc.rc: line 480: syntax error in conditional expression: unexpected token `;'
./mosc.rc: line 480: syntax error near `;['
./mosc.rc: line 480: `if [[ "\033[1;42;35m" =~ \[[0123456789]+;[0123456789]+;[0123456789]+m ]] ; then'
```

Escaping the `;` seems to work.

```
if [[ "$1" =~ \[[0123456789]+\;[0123456789]+\;[0123456789]+m ]] ; then
```

Comment: And what happens when you "play with" that? Is there an input that it's failing to match? An error message? Try to be specific.

Comment: Please add multiple examples for $1 to your question (no comment here) which should match and not match.